# Given three positive numbers $a,b,c$ so that $a\leqq b\leqq c$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+1.4b}{1.4a+b}\geqq 3$ .

Tags: inequality, constants, jensen-inequality

> Given three positive numbers $a, b, c$ so that $a\leqq b\leqq c$. Prove that
>   $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\,\frac{a+ 1.4\,b}{1.4\,a+ b}\geqq 3$$

$$\because\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+ b}{7a+ 5b}\geqq \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\because\sum\limits_{cyc}\left ( (a+ b)(7b+ 5c)(7c+ 5a) \right )\geqq \frac{1}{2}\prod\limits_{cyc}(7a+ 5b)$$
$$\because 95\sum\limits_{cyc}ab^{2}+ 119\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}b+ 222abc\geqq \frac{1}{2}\left ( 95\sum\limits_{cyc}ab^{2}+ 245\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}b+ 468abc \right )$$
$$\because 15\sum\limits_{cyc}ab^{2}- 7\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}b- 24abc\geqq 0$$
$$\because 15\left ( \sum\limits_{cyc}(b- c)a^{2} \right )+ 8(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{2}b- 3abc)\geqq 0$$
$$\because 15\sum\limits_{cyc}(b- c)a^{2}\geqq 0$$
We will prove $\sum\limits_{cyc}(b- c)a^{2}\geqq 0$ so that $0< a\leqq b\leqq c$ involving to *Jensen inequality*, like above :
$$(b- c)a^{2}+ (a- b)c^{2}\geqq (b- c+ a- b)\left ( \frac{(b- c)a+ (a- b)c}{b- c+ a- b} \right )^{2}$$
Is true? (So how about another solutions here!?)

Comment: What is SHEDtechniQ?

Comment: You already assumed $a\geq b\geq c>0$ in order to define $k=b/c$.  There is no need for buffalo way.

Comment: But what is **BW**?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel [The Buffalo way](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/buffalo-way/info)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  From the context, I think **BW** means buffalo way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $K= \dfrac{7}{5}$ it's wrong. Try $(a,b,c)= (25,9,1).$

For $a\leq b\leq c$ we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(15a^2c-7a^2b-8abc)\geq 0$$ or
$$8(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b-3abc)+7(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\geq 0,$$ which is true by AM-GM.

Comment: For $a\geq b\geq c$ and $k=\frac{7}{5}$ it's wrong. For $a\leq b\leq c$ it's true.